# R: how to convert factor vector into numeric (advices from other questions did not work)

Tags: r, type-conversion

I am trying to convert a factor vector into numeric value without any changes in the value.

I looked up and found out some functions like

```
         bonds1 <- as.numeric(as.character(bonds$price)) 
         Warning message:
         NAs introduced by coercion 

         bonds1 <- as.numeric(levels(bonds$price)[bonds$price])
         Warning message:
         NAs introduced by coercion
```

but as it is shown above, warning signs keep coming up. Any ideas on why this is not working?

[figured it out]

It was the commas in bonds$price

```
         bonds$price <- as.numeric(gsub(",","",bonds$price))
```

Comment: @HubertL the column is a price of a bond. It looks something like this `10,045.26, 10,030.25....` I don't know why these prices cannot be converted to numeric..

Comment: Its the commas that creates the warning.

Comment: @DeshanR ahh figured it out thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Like @HurbtL has mentioned it seems values are not convertible.

Check these SO answers on how to avoid this warning

**Parse numerics with commas:**

[how to avoid "Warning message: NAs introduced by coercion" in as.numeric()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25593424/how-to-avoid-warning-message-nas-introduced-by-coercion-in-as-numeric)

```
N1 <- c("1000", "1,000", "10000", "10,000")
as.numeric(N1)
##
[1]  1000    NA 10000    NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
##
> N2 <- gsub(",","",N1)
> as.numeric(N2)
[1]  1000  1000 10000 10000
```

**Supress warning**

[How to avoid warning when introducing NAs by coercion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984989/how-to-avoid-warning-when-introducing-nas-by-coercion)

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the comma with `gsub()`:

```
as.numeric(gsub(",","",as.character(factor(c("1,000.23","2.2", "one")))))
[1] 1000.23    2.20      NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```